# Suppose that $(P,<)$ and $(P',<')$ are isomorphic and that $(P',<')$ has a completion. Then $(P,<)$ has a completion

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

This is from textbook *Introduction to Set Theory* by Karel Hrbacek and Thomas Jech.

---

> **5.3 Theorem** Let $(P, <)$ be a dense linearly ordered set without endpoints. Then there exists a complete linearly ordered set $(C,\prec)$ such that
>
> (a) $P\subseteq C$.
>
> (b) If $p,q\in P$ then $p < q$ if and only if $p \prec q$ ($<$ coincides with $\prec$ on $P$).
>
> (c) $P$ is dense in $C$, i.e., for any $a,b\in C$ such that $a\prec b$, there is $p\in P$ with $a\prec p \prec b$.
>
> (d) $C$ does not have endpoints.
>
> The linearly ordered set $(C,\prec)$ is called the completion of $(P, <)$.

---

In proving this theorem, the authors define a new set $(P',<')$ which is isomorphic to $(P,<)$. Then they define $(C',\prec')$ and prove that $(C',\prec')$ is the completion of $(P',<')$. Finally the authors conclude that:

> We intend to show that $(C',\prec')$ is a completion of $(P',<')$. Since $(P,<)$ and $(P',<')$ are isomorphic, it follows that $(P,<)$ has a completion.

I'm unable to understand why the authors have that conclusion.

1. How do we know that a completion of $(P,<)$ does exist?
2. How do we define a completion of $(P,<)$ explicitly from $(C',\prec')$?

Thank you for your clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the isomorphism $f\colon (P,<)\to (P',<')$. Now define
$$
C=(C'\setminus P')\cup P
$$
and a map $g\colon C\to C'$ by
$$
g(x)=\begin{cases}
f(x) & x\in P \\
x & x\notin P
\end{cases}
$$
Finally define, for $x,y\in C$, $x\prec y$ if and only if $g(x)\prec'g(y)$.

Now prove that $g\colon (C,\prec)\to(C,\prec')$ is an isomorphism and that $(C,\prec)$ has the required properties.

Comment: Hi @egreg! I think that if $(C'\setminus P')\cap P \neq \emptyset$, then $g$ may be not surjective. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: @LeAnhDung I guess that the construction of $C'$ makes sure that $C'\cap P=\emptyset$. If not, do it for yourself.

Comment: Actually, $C'$ is the set of all Dedekind cuts generated from $P$. If I assume Axiom of Foundation, it is easy to prove that $C'\cap P=\emptyset$. I would like to ask if we can prove $C'\cap P=\emptyset$ without appealing to Axiom of Foundation.

Comment: @LeAnhDung You're doing hair splitting. Define $(C'',\prec'')$ as the elements of $C'$ painted red, assuming the elements of $P$ are not painted. I'm sure you can formalize a notion of “painting red”.

Comment: I got it @egreg. Thank you so much for your dedicated help!

Comment: @Akira What is the notion of "painting red"?

Comment: @Alphie Just a way of saying “the objects are the same, but we pretend they aren't”. For instance, if $q$ is not an element of $C'$, you can consider $C''=\{(x,q):x\in C'\}$.

Comment: @egreg Ok but I still don't see how you can avoid the use of the axiom of foundation to show that $C'\cap P=\emptyset$.

Comment: @Alphie Do you reject foundation?

Comment: @egreg Not at all but I thought you were suggesting an argument not making use of this axiom. Maybe I misunderstood.